How can I keep form of scalar product of two vectors?
Let
a = {-6, 1, -12};
b = {x - 2, y - 1, z - 5}

be two vectors. I want to keep form of scalar product of a and b in the form
-6 (x-2) + 1 (y-1) - 12 (z-5).
I used
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {-6, 1, -12};
b = {x - 2, y - 1, z - 5};
TraditionalForm[a . b]

and get

-6 (x-2)+y-12 (z-5)-1

How can I get the form -6 (x-2) + 1 (y-1) - 12 (z-5)?


How can I get the form -6 (x-2) + 1 (y-1) - 12 (z-5)?

One possible way
a = {-6, 1, -12};
b = {x - 2, y - 1, z - 5};
(HoldForm /@ a) . b


 ReleaseHold[%]


Or you could do
a={-6,1,-12};
b={x-2,y-1,z-5};
a.(HoldForm /@b)



Your results doen't like my request.

Do you mean the order of the terms? And -2+x va. x-2 ?
In this case you can try this. But you will be fighting against Mathematica all the time. Mathematica is about computation. For final presentation, use Latex. But here is one way. May be there is easier way. I do not know.
a = {-6, 1, -12}
b = {HoldForm[x - 2], HoldForm[y - 1], HoldForm[z - 5]}
ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]
Plus @@ First@Last@Reap@Do[Sow[a[[n]]*b[[n]]], {n, 1, 3}]



Your results doen't like my request.
